# MVC4 Form verification, maybe Action Filters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, action-filter

I need to add two kinds of verification to a comment form I’ve built. Some type on human verification and some type of email verification. Would putting these into Action Filters be a good way to go?

I don’t want to use Google’s recapture, I don’t like using it myself when I’m asked too and I have seen some other clever options around the place but that’s for another thread.

Is this the type of thing I should/could put into Action Filters???

Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this thanks to a great guy at asp.net, so I will quote him, CodeHobo said,

“You implement this by using the concept of a buddy class. Basically you create another class with public properties that match the properties of your EF model. You apply the validation attributes to your "buddy class".

Then create a partial class to match your EF model (EF generates partial classes for all models). You add an attribute to your partial that points to your "buddy class". Basically you are telling mvc to use the validations in the associated class instead of the EF model.

Take a look at this

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-(data)/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs”

This worked for me and was amazingly simple to implement thanks to MVC.